# HP Stream Laptop does not wake up from suspend

Tags: suspend, wakeup

I use a HP Stream Laptop (ak0291ng) with ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome Flashback. Don't know which key to press for wakeup from suspend mode. (From the Gnome Menu or after closing the laptop) Hitting the Power button does not work. The Power Led is blinking and i have to shutdown the computer by pressing and holding the power button.